extract variable from meson dependency
I am new to meson and am stumped by a really basic issue : accessing the executable which was found in a dependency.
Concretely, I am trying to import protobuf (already present on system) and generate some protobuf source files in meson, similar to what is done here: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/1622
This is the relevant part of my meson.build file:
protobuf_dep = dependency('protobuf',
  method: 'cmake',
  modules: [ 'protobuf::protoc', 'protobuf::libprotobuf', 'protobuf::libprotoc' ],
  required: true,
)

Meson is able to find the corresponding targets:
Run-time dependency protobuf (modules: protobuf::libprotobuf, protobuf::libprotoc, protobuf::protoc) found: YES 27.0.0
Now I would like to use protobuf::protoc in a command, but I cannot manage to extract it. Both protoc and protoc-27.0.0 (symlink) can be found at the location specified by the cmake_prefix_path.
protoc = find_program('protoc') does not find it, I also tried searching for protobuf::protoc and protoc-27.0.0. I tried to `protobuf_deb.get_variable(...)' with all possible names without success.
Any pointer on how I can access these objects would be appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT: even simple calls such as protobuf_dep.get_variable(cmake : 'PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS') fail, which according to https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/6660 should work?
EDIT 2: As a workaround I am now passing the explicit binary dir to find_program. It works, but is an ugly solution imho. I'm sure there is a better way.
